# Is there a way to reupload a file to S3 without having to reset a custom MIME type?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have two xml files that need (or really want) to be served with specific MIME types that S3 doesn't serve by default. The files are sitemap.xml and rss.xml served as `application/xml` and `application/rss+xml` respectively.

I am able to set the Content-Type header for these files no problem.

[image]

The problem is every time my site changes these files change. I should say that my site is completely static from a web server perspective. My site is updated by me building the files locally and uploading them to S3. When I upload my updated sitemap.xml and rss.xml files though, S3 nukes my custom Content-Type settings.

Is there a way to get it to associate these settings with the name of the file as opposed to the instance of the file?

Comment: What tool are you using to upload the replacement files?

Comment: I'm using the AWS console.